# Firebase API in JavaScript and therefore public, concern for Auth?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I appreciate that variants of this have been posted before, however I am not seeing one that directly hits this concern.  The Firebase recommendation is that for Web interfaces the JS includes enough information for the client side JS to identify the application in question.  This config can be used for all the activities that are needed.  In my case :

createUserWithEmailAndPassword / signInWithEmailAndPassword / sendEmailVerification

Basically this means that anybody can simply start creating users for my application.  They can also sign-in, which means any data rules I have that, an example like below, are now open to the world for updates.

```
    service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    match /clubs/{club}
    {
       allow write: if isSignedIn();
       allow read: if true;
    }
}
```

Here is what I have done.  I have added a Role to the User list, and the User list is not writeable by anybody except my back-end processes which bypass the rules.

Therefore although malicious people could create accounts and sign-in, they could never give themselves the most vital Roles.  It still leaves me with 2 issues, firstly it just does not feel quite right :-), secondly how do I know which accounts are valid people trying to sign-up for my application and which are bogus.  Those that are valid need their Role updating in the back-end.  Right now when I have like 5 users of my app it is ok (haha), but how do people manage this in a more voluminous application?

I appreciate you taking the time to read this and I appreciate any thoughts and / or suggestion you might have.

Answer (score 0):

if you need more granular control around your roles, you can check [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Also, there are a few posts around which tell you a few patterns, take a look:

- [Controlling Data Access Using Firebase Auth Custom Claims](https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a)
- [Patterns for security with Firebase: supercharged custom claims with Firestore and Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-supercharged-custom-claims-with-firestore-and-cloud-functions-bb8f46b24e11)

there's enough information there to get you started.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Thanks for the article I posted the same question reworded there as the theme misses the point.  How does their backend code (to add custom claim) know which account is special and which was just randomly created.  That thread is old, not sure anyone will post there.

Comment: You have the context available on the function to get the user id, if you need further logic you hve to implement it yourself

Comment: Thanks Andres, I am using the users UID to protect the necessary data.  That is working very well.   See snippet from question.  But I am wondering how my backend code knows which users are valid users.  As above, not a problem while I have 5 users but will be over time.

Comment: you need to implement the logic yourself to know "which account is special and which was randomly created", you can set a cloud function which you can hit and fetch your user collection and make decisions based on that, your custom claims are created on the backend.